# Compare two cells and place the result in a third

Tags: excel, if-statement, compare, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I would like to compare in Excel two fields per column and place a flag in a third field:

If the table looks like:

```
+---+--------+----------+---+
|   |   A    |    B     | C |
+---+--------+----------+---+
| 1 | 100,00 | 100,00   |   |
| 2 | 100,00 | 50,00    |   |
| 3 | 100,00 | 200,00   | x |
+---+--------+----------+---+
```

If B is twice the value of A then C should get a flag.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try, in C1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(B1=A1*2,"x","")
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: that's interesting! Never knew that :) (the "great it works!" comments with no accept do annoy me)